# Do nvidia drivers update?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

In order to get the latest nvidia drivers for my Nvidia GTX 560 ti, I am installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers from their website. Will these update automatically? Is it worthwhile to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it/are going *to* install it from their website, **no**.

Because you manually installed the drivers there isn't any way, unless that functionality is programmed into the driver (which I believe it isn't.)

As for the worthwhile-ness of updating your drivers, that's normally a good idea. You get bug fixes and usually better performance.

However, it's smart to back up your system prior to doing so because driver updates can occasionally mess up your system.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to install either using apt-get or through the drivers menu, as these will update and also re-compile when you get a new kernel version (which your downloaded one will not)